# Grub menu disappeared after using grub customizer(in ubuntu) to make windows 10 as default os

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, bios, boot-repair

I was using windows 10 earlier. I wanted to use Ubuntu also,so I decided to make dual boot system. I made bootable pendrive and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on dual boot in my pc. For first two days everything was working well , only some small problems like the clock of both operating systems showed different time(this was not main problem).

Main problem arised when I decided to make windows 10 as default Operating system. For this I installed grub customizer from ubuntu software. In grub customizer I moved windows boot manager to top (I took help of youtube channel "Its FOSS-Linux Blog"). I also changed boot default entry time to 15 seconds. I saved changes and restarted my pc but now grub menu didn't appear and windows opened directly. After that every time I start my pc, windows 10 directly opens.

Till now I haven't tried anything to solve the problem because I am afraid of data loss .I have lots of data on my computer hard disk and don't have any extra pc or external hard drive to take backup.

I think this problem may be solved by changing "set timeout_style=hidden" to "set timeout_style=visible" in grub.cfg file(saw this in a youtube video), but for accessing this file I will have to open ubuntu which will not be possible without grub menu.

Please help me for making grub menu again visible.

About my pc:

BIOS mode - legacy.

Partition mode- MBR.

It is an old pc with intel core i3 second generation processor.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable Ubuntu usb drive using windows. Check [this to know](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) how.Now boot into the live ubuntu session and install grub repair using terminal.Run the following in terminal.

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Now click on recommended repairs and follow on screen instructions.

Credits-[Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#line-9:%7E:text=when%20GRUB%20is%20not%20displayed%20anymore)

Comment: Will I have to back up my data or not needed??

Comment: Thanks a lot  my problem is solved with your guidance .....Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry about data lose. This situation is not so rare and many newbies would end up in a situation like this especially when trying to dual boot. The solution for this is well documented. Use the installation medium you used for Ubuntu installation previously and follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: Thanks a lot  my problem is solved with your guidance .....Thank you very much

Comment: But the old problem is back (difference in clock time of both OS ). Please help

Comment: It's not a major problem and simplest solution is to set automatically update timezone and time in the either of the OS.